# Xamarin Forms localization and mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, localization, xamarin.forms

I'm receiving data from the server and I should localize it and put it in ViewModel.

I serialize data from responce in json format to .NET object.

For example, I need to localize boolean variable "True" or "False" to English or different UI language to "Free" or "Busy".

I use resources files (*.resx) for localization.

Suggest me the best way to do it in Xamarin.Forms app with classic MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) is a very detailed documentation of how would add localization to your project using resx.

In your case when you get the True then I request the localized key for "Free" .

For example if you have a property called Status you do localize it this way

```
 public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                if (_isBusy)
                {
                    return AppResources.Status_Busy;
                }
                else
                {
                    return AppResources.Status_Free;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _status = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a *.resx files. I know how to localize static data but I don't know how do it with a dynamic data

Comment: I would put switch cases or If statements . is that what you mean ? can you put some code if I am not answering correctly ?

Comment: I get data from server and I use MVVM and bindingContext to XAML. I want to put localized string from ViewModel to XAML.

Comment: Check my updated answer , and let me know if that does not answer your question.

Comment: Where does `_localizer` come from? The main part of the answer seems to drop in from the sky.

Comment: I put localizer there just to indicate where the localization process would be, it  is just a psudo code . anyway , I have replaced it to match the documentation .